# Complex select from cache Laravel 5.2

Tags: caching, laravel-5

I can't find informations about: how make complex select from cache Laravel 5.

I have query :

```
$companys = Company::with(['comments' => function ($query) {

            $query->where('status', '=', 'done');

            }])->withCount('comments')->has('comments')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(8);
```

I need caching this query.

I want firstly caching all companys with commets and after make query to cache for get random companys with count comments and pagination.

Somethink like this:

```
$cache_companys =  Cache::remember('companys', 30, function () {

          return Company::with('comments')->get();

        });
```

and after from $cache_companys get my companys for pagination.

I tryed make:

```
$companys = Cache::remember('companys', 30, function () {

          return Company::with(['comments' => function ($query) {

                $query->where('status', '=', 'done');

                }])->withCount('comments')->has('comments')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(8);
        });
```

but in this case at every pages of paginations was same companys.

Help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution of my question:

```
$currentPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$companys = Cache::remember('companys-'.$currentPage, 30, function () {

          return Company::with(['comments' => function ($query) {

                $query->where('status', '=', 'done');

                }])->withCount('comments')->has('comments')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(8);
        });
```